# Calculate remaining days of leave - php

Tags: php

Say:

The start day is January 5 and the end is January 10 and the current date is January 7. I want to output the remaining days which is 3.

Comment: You'll need some code for that.

Comment: Show us whta you have tried! and also have a look at the PHP Time .diff()-Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest method is like this.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2015-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2010-02-05");

$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```